# Java Applets and Proxies

Tags: java, networking, proxy, applet, socks

Assuming that I use the following code to connect to a SOCKS5 proxy, would connections or packets sent by an applet that I instantiate go through the same proxy?

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxySet", "true");
System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxyHost", "*.*.*.*");
System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxyPort", "*");
```

Applet is started using a classloader object from which a newInstance is created.

```
classLoader = new CustomClassLoader(/* Hashmap of byte arrays */); // Custom classloader that works using byte arrays
Applet applet = (Applet) classLoader.loadClass("class").newInstance();
applet.setStub(stub);
applet.init();
applet.start();
frame.add(applet);
```

Comment: How do you intend to instantiate the Applet (what is it your class-loader hack does)? Where in the Applet(?) are you setting the above `socksProxy` settings? Finally, are the settings for a publicly routable IP address?

Comment: I set the settings in the main class, which then loads an applet. The hack simply allows me to use byte arrays instead of limiting me. It loads classes as normal.

Comment: Start over; a main class **or** an applet? They are not synonymous.

Comment: A main class **and** an applet. The applet is in the form of an object.

Comment: There isn't enough code here for me to test it; does it work?

Comment: That's my entire question.

Comment: There is [no such property as `socksProxySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Comment: That's odd, I thought there was one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the answer to this question is **yes**.

The following code:

```
public class TestApplet extends Applet {

    private String ip;

    public void init() {
        try {
            URL ipCheck = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ipCheck.openStream()));
            ip = bufferedReader.readLine();
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.drawString("Current IP: " + ip, 10, 20);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Boot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxySet", "true");
        System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxyHost", "71.9.127.141"); //Credits to HideMyAss.com
        System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxyPort", "28045");//Credits to HideMyAss.com

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                TestApplet testApplet = new TestApplet();
                testApplet.init();
                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
                jFrame.setContentPane(testApplet);
                jFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tyler, if I understand your question correctly - yes. But this comes with a caveat: the System properties that you set will persist only across the current JVM instantiation.

So, if like your example shows you set the properties and execute the Applet on the same JVM you should be fine.